# How to prevent the propagation of an onclick event to a child element in Vaadin?

Tags: java, vaadin

I need that when I click to an image element an event is executed, and on the other side, when I click on `UI.getCurrent()` element  another distinct event is executed

I have within the UI element an AbsoluteLayout (leftLayout) and within this is located the image.

Actually, when I click in the image, the two events are triggered: the "Game Over" notification is displayed and under it appears the "Good" notification.

**How to prevent the propagation of the onclick `UI.getCurrent()` event to the image element?**

```
public class VaadinmatchinggameUI extends UI{
   //...
   private AbsoluteLayout leftLayout = new AbsoluteLayout();
   ///...
    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
     //...
     UI.getCurrent().addClickListener(new ClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void click(ClickEvent event) {
            Notification.show("Game Over");
        }
    }); 
     addImg();
    }
    private void addImg() {
      //...
      FileResource resource = new FileResource(new File(PATH));
      Image face = face = new Image(null, resource);
      leftLayout.addComponent(face, "top:" + randomTop 
                    + "px; left:" + randomLeft + "px;");
      face.addClickListener(new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void click(ClickEvent event) {
                Notification.show("Good", Notification.Type.HUMANIZED_MESSAGE);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to add click listener on the layout and when you catch click check click position.

See the code below:

```
// Listen for layout click events
layout.addListener(new LayoutClickListener() {
 public void layoutClick(LayoutClickEvent event) {

     // Get the child component which was clicked
     Component child = event.getChildComponent();

     if (child == null) {
         // Not over any child component
         getWindow().showNotification(
                 "The click was not over any component.");
     } else {
         // Over a child component
         getWindow().showNotification(
                 "The click was over a "
                         + child.getClass().getCanonicalName());
     }
 }
});
```

the complete example you can find on the link: [ClickableLayoutBasicExample.java](https://dev.vaadin.com/svn/addons/XS/vaadin-xs-demo/src/main/java/com/vaadin/demo/sampler/features/layouts/ClickableLayoutBasicExample.java)

This code is tested for Vaadin 6, but with small modifications will work for Vaadin 7 also.

Comment: Thanks, I am using vaadin version 7.6.3 and this works fine, without modifications